# Kotlin: android app keeps on crashing due to setOnClickListener{} (following official android tutorial)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been following the official android kotlin tutorial and trying to make the dice app, but for some reason it keeps crashing when I try to run the app on the emulator. It's breaking on my setOnClickListener line, but this is literally the exact code from the tutorial.

MainActivtiy.kt:

```
package com.example.diceroll
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener{rollDice()}


    }
    private fun rollDice() {
       
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val dieRoll = dice.roll()
        val result: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        result.text = dieRoll.toString()
    }


}

public class Dice(private val numSides: Int) {
    fun roll(): Int { // tells kotlin that this function will return an integer
        return (1..numSides).random()

    }

}
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}





task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="30sp"
            tools:text="Bagels"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/roll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="161dp" android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="396dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
W/xample.dicerol: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory;->metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; (blacklist, linking, denied)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.diceroll, PID: 11165
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.example.diceroll.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You're missing the ID for the TextView in your layout. You need to add an extra attribute: `android:id="@+id/textView"`

Comment: I have this in the textview, same row as the top constraint

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed it there.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted works fine, try going to Build > Clean Project

then run it again.

Comment: no luck unfortunately, still gives the error

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your app's build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

this seems to be the lambda function's issue

Comment: tried this, but now the gradle file is giving an error:

problem occurred evaluating root project 'DiceRoll'.
> Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments [build_cquzywcsap35sx9d9mcp1f9v6$_run_closure3@738a0517] on root project 'DiceRoll' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: can you share you app's build.gradle?